# Best way to return an enumeration of files with certain extensions

Tags: c#, file, enumeration

I need to create an enumeration of spreadsheets based on their file extensions, I need two options either recursive and no recursive and I need to return the enumeration from my enumeration. I have this code

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Enumeration;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Enumerate_org = System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>;

        public IEnumerable<T> Enumerate_Original<T>(string argument1, string argument3)
        {
            Enumerate_org<T> org_enumeration = new Enumerate_org<T>();

            // Recurse enumeration of original spreadsheets from input directory
            if (argument3 == "Recurse=Yes")
            {
                org_enumeration = Directory.EnumerateFiles(argument1, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                .Where(file => file.EndsWith(".fods") || file.EndsWith(".ods") || file.EndsWith(".ots") || file.EndsWith("xla") || file.EndsWith(".xls") || file.EndsWith(".xls") || file.EndsWith(".xlt") || file.EndsWith(".xlam") || file.EndsWith(".xlsb") || file.EndsWith(".xlsm") || file.EndsWith(".xlsx") || file.EndsWith(".xltm") || file.EndsWith(".xltx"))
                .ToList();

                return org_enumeration;
            }

            // No recurse enumeration
            else
            {
                org_enumeration = Directory.EnumerateFiles(argument1, "*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
                .Where(file => file.EndsWith(".fods") || file.EndsWith(".ods") || file.EndsWith(".ots") || file.EndsWith("xla") || file.EndsWith(".xls") || file.EndsWith(".xls") || file.EndsWith(".xlt") || file.EndsWith(".xlam") || file.EndsWith(".xlsb") || file.EndsWith(".xlsm") || file.EndsWith(".xlsx") || file.EndsWith(".xltm") || file.EndsWith(".xltx"))
                .ToList();

                return org_enumeration;
            }

        }
```

But I get the error

```
The using alias 'Enumerate_org' cannot be used with type arguments
```

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. I have an array of file extensions that are accepted. How to replace

```
file.EndsWith("a specific extension")
```

with the same search but trying to match any of the entries in the extensions array?

Comment: *"What am I doing wrong?"*  - For one, your title has nothing to do with the error message you're getting. *That* should be your title because *that* is what your question is really about.

Comment: Have you considered using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles?view=net-6.0#system-io-directory-getfiles(system-string-system-string) or another overload? You can simply search all files using *.xsl for example. There is also a option for scanning all subdirectories as well.

Comment: `Enumerate_org` is `IEnumerable<string>`, so what does `IEnumerable<string><T>` (`Enumerate_org<T>`)  is supposed to mean?

Comment: *using Enumerate_org = System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>;* I'm not sure this is legal C# code. What are you trying to do here?

Comment: Furthermore, because `Enumerate_org` is an interface, what do you expect `new Enumerate_org<T>()` to do? You can't instantiate an interface.

Comment: Frankly, I see no point in the alias. Remove that and you should see things more clearly.

Comment: @topsail that is legal, it's an alias. It's just pointless in OPs example.

Comment: @topsail Perfectly legal, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive#using-alias

Comment: Oh I guess I never did it in C# - always thought it was using ... as ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is because you declare a type alias for a closed (specific, resolved) type `<string>` in `using Enumerate_org = System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>;`, then attempt to use it `new Enumerate_org<T>();`

This is wrong in two ways - you cannot re-type or "untype" (go back to `<T>` AND you can't instantiate an interface `IEnumerable`.

You could have used the alias and said `Enumerate_org org_enumeration = new List<string>();` but that makes the type alias redundant (so get rid of it and just say `using System.Collections.Generic;`).

Then...

```
var org_enumeration = new List<string>(); // question #1, instead of new System.Collections.Generic.List<string>();
:
... Where(file => ExtensionsList.Contains(Path.GetExtension(file)))... // question #2
```

Do return `IEnumerable<string>` and do not call `.ToList()` on your enumerables before returning. Here is some reading: [C#: IEnumerable, yield return, and lazy evaluation](https://stackoverflow.blog/2022/06/15/c-ienumerable-yield-return-and-lazy-evaluation/)

Comment: Thanks. I used your codebits and I could not immediately get it working, but you gave me a hint to return a list instead and I pursued that path. I had to cast the enumeration to a list type though by writing (List<string>)

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using [Path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path?view=net-6.0) class in order to obtain extension:

```
// Since we enumerate files' names, we return IEnumerable<string>
public static IEnumerable<string> Enumerate_Original(string argument1,
                                                     string argument3) {
  var extensions = new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) {
    //TODO: add all required extensions here
    ".fods",
    ".ods",
  };

  return Directory
    .EnumerateFiles(argument1, 
                    "*.*", 
                    argument3 == "Recurse=Yes" 
                      ? SearchOption.AllDirectories 
                      : SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
    .Where(file => extensions.Contains(Path.GetExtension(file)));
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't test if your solution works, but I upvoted it. If anyone else can confirm it works, I will mark it as a solution.

Answer (score 0):

AlanK got me on the right track and I turned the `IEnumerable` into a list instead. The code is now:

```cs
public List<string> Enumerate_Original(string argument1, string argument3)
{    
    var org_enumeration = new List<string>();

    // Recurse enumeration of original spreadsheets from input directory
    if (argument3 == "Recurse=Yes")
    {
        org_enumeration = (List<string>)Directory.EnumerateFiles(argument1, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
            .Where(file => file_format.Contains(Path.GetExtension(file)))
            .ToList();

        return org_enumeration;
    }

    // No recurse enumeration
    else
    {
        org_enumeration = (List<string>)Directory.EnumerateFiles(argument1, "*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
           .Where(file => file_format.Contains(Path.GetExtension(file)))
           .ToList();

        return org_enumeration;
    }
}
```

Comment: There are good reasons for returning `IEnumerable<string>` and - importantly - not doing the `.ToList()'s.  Here is some good reading that covers "Lazy Evaluation" - an essential topic to understand in making efficient use of LINQ: [https://stackoverflow.blog/2022/06/15/c-ienumerable-yield-return-and-lazy-evaluation/][1]  I have also improved my answer to make it more complete, rather than just a couple of hints.  Thanks.